# Bootcamp Windows 7 loading time optimization

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I've created a bootcamp partition and successfully installed Windows 7 there. The problem is that Windows loads too slow - there is a white pointer on black screen blinking for 2 or 3 minutes before system starts loading, so total loading time exeeds to 4 minutes.
How can I reduce Windows loading time?
I'm using MBP 2010 MC371, so there should be no perfomance problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the solution on [http://viperfx07.blogspot.com](http://viperfx07.blogspot.com/2010/01/tutorial-fixing-slow-booting-in-windows.html) but I haven't had the problem myself so I can't say whether it will solve your issue

*Just to note that this [may be due to your copy of Windows not being genuine](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r22969889-OS-X-Bootcamp-Windows-7-Ultra-Slow-Boot~start=20)*

Comment: I don't think the Windows Genuine Advantage kicks in until Windows is loaded, and this sounds like it's in the pre-boot environment.

Comment: It's not WGA kicking in, it's the bootloader looking for firmware which doesn't exist and it pauses because it can't find it.

Comment: Finally, I've managed to fix my problem! Thanks! The link to http://viperfx07.blogspot.com is great!

Comment: Thats good to hear well done :)