# Booting gets stuck for a minute when using Bootcamp on Windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, startup

I installed Windows 10 using the official ISO and one of the serials I have with MSDN. When I reboot my Macbook Air 2013 it gets stuck on a black screen for around a minute and then start loading Windows. I only have a windows partition at the moment.

I tried resetting the NVRAM. Didn't help.

I followed the advice [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/bootcamp-windows-7-loading-time-optimization) but that didn't help either since it seems to be for Windows 7 only.

Comment: When you say you "only have a windows partition at the moment", do you mean you do not have OS X installed?

Comment: yes, just windows.

Comment: I now assume you installed Windows using a USB flash drive. How did you create the flash drive without using the Boot Camp Assistant that comes with OS X? Also, If you were given the option to choose between two DVD icons labeled "Windows" and "EFI", which did you choose?

Comment: i created it with the assistant, rebooted and deleted the osx partition. dont remember about efi

Comment: If you used the Boot Camp Assistant, then you did not see the DVD icons. Did you run and install the Boot Camp Support Software after windows finished installing? I assume this software was on the USB flash drive.

Comment: yes i installed all the drivers. it got stuck on realtek audio but i managed to install it manually after.

Comment: I only have one question left. Open the control panel and select the Boot Camp icon to open the window. Choose to reboot to the Windows partition. This should "bless" the windows partition. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: My partition has been blessed! Now it takes just a second and start loading Windows. Nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not blessed the Windows partition. On a Mac, the blessed partition is the one that the firmware will try to boot first.

Open the control panel and select the Boot Camp icon to open the window. Choose to reboot to the Windows partition. This should "bless" the windows partition.