# Old MacPro (2,1) with Windows 7 runs extremely slow?

Tags: windows, mac-pro

I installed (native, so no vm) Windows 7 (64 bits) on my old MacPro2,1. With 10GB RAM I would have though it would run pretty decent. But no, its *extremely* slow and I have no clue what causes it. I'm guessing a setting or a wrong driver.

Just for slow indications, minutes pass for login screen. Also the HDD makes a ton of noise (seems reading/writing). I did checked the drive, appears to be fine (SMART status).

Anybody recognises this issue?, any fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Win7 64 isn't supported on a 2,1, only Win7 32, so you probably don't have the right drivers. https://support.apple.com/HT205016 Having said that, the best way to speed up any OS these days is use an SSD.

Comment: Good question. Where did you get the drivers? By this I mean the "Boot Camp Support Software" or "Windows Support Software". Also, did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 7 or did you install Windows 7 without OS X installed? Did you use an DVD drive to install Windows 7? Did Windows 7 have SP1 already included?

Comment: Yes, correct there is a problem installing the normal CD. But you can make a custom boot CD that installs the 64 bit version. The problem is not the CPU, but the BIOS that only supports 32-bit booting. However, I did install 64 bit Windows and all 10 GB is shown as available. I know SSD is faster, but this has nothing todo with it. Its *extremely* slow. I will check all drivers, maybe there are some 32 bit installed.

Comment: I understand you have a 32 EFI, but I assume this has no effect on the BIOS. Did you install Windows 7 to BIOS boot? Again I ask, where did you get the drivers? It is important you answer this question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I got the drives from Apple. I just checked, there was AVG (32 bit??) and DropBox (also 32 bit) version installed. I removed those, that seems a bit better. Yet i still see some programs running in 32 bit mode.

Comment: You do not understand what I mean by drivers. Let my try rewording my question. After installing Windows 7, you need to install the "Boot Camp Support Software" provided by Apple. Did you do this? If so, did you download this software from a website or by using the Boot Camp Assistant. If you used a website, then which version did you download?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I think I do understand, i took them from Apple. Its some time ago, so im not 100% sure which version, anyway i can check? I think it was this one: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1720?locale=en_US

Comment: Ok, you have the wrong download. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have a 32 bit EFI. I do not think this has anything to do with the BIOS. Since you have already installed 64 bit Windows 7, I am guessing it does not.

In your comments, you say you modified the CD. So I can assume you have a working DVD drive. When you say you modified, [I assume this involved `oscdimg`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172048/select-cd-rom-boot-type-error-during-windows-install).

Apple does not officially support 64 bit Windows on your model Mac. Well, I have a 2007 iMac, which Apple does not officially support 64 bit Windows, yet I have run 64 bit Windows 7 and I am currently running 64 bit Windows 10.

I assume the Windows 7 installation DVD has Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1) or later included. This is a requirement according to the Apple website [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016).

You have to installed Windows for a BIOS boot. It not a question of whether you can install to use a EFI boot, but rather the restriction is in the drivers. The Boot Camp Support Software for your Mac assumes you are using a BIOS boot method. This software includes the drivers for your Mac.

You can download the Boot Camp Support Software for your Mac from the website [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US). Since you have a 64 bit install, you might have trouble installing this download. If so, refer to the website [Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-or-8).

Finally, you might not be blessed. If not, then your Mac would be slow to boot. [Click on this link for instructions on how to bless your Windows 7 install.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229247/booting-gets-stuck-for-a-minute-when-using-bootcamp-on-windows-10/229260#229260) The instruction assume you have already installed the Boot Camp Support Software.

> Note: Many people have assumed the latest release the the Boot Camp Support Software should always be used. This is completely wrong. You have to use the Boot Camp Support Software released for your model Mac. Windows is designed to accept older drivers and even 32 bit drivers when the current driver is not available. So, if you decide to install 64 bit Windows 10 on your Mac, you would still use the same Boot Camp Support Software as for a 32 bit Windows 7 install.